# How to set marker in center of google map in android?

Tags: android

I am Building an android application where user select there favorite address using google map.

Now I had implement my Google map as Always the last value of center position is fixed in Lat,Long of google map.

Now I need an center marker with it that display the user there selected Location in map.

Here is my code -

```
@Override
public void onTouchDown(MotionEvent event) {
    mDownCameraPosition = getMap().getMap().getCameraPosition();
}

@Override
public void onTouchUp(MotionEvent event) {
    mUpCameraPosition = getMap().getMap().getCameraPosition();
    updateCameraPositionData();
}

private void updateCameraPositionData() {
    mDownCenterLat.setText(String
            .valueOf(mDownCameraPosition.target.latitude));
    mDownCenterLong.setText(String
            .valueOf(mDownCameraPosition.target.longitude));
    mDownZoom.setText(String.valueOf(mDownCameraPosition.zoom));
    mUpCenterLat.setText(String.valueOf(mUpCameraPosition.target.latitude));
    mUpCenterLong.setText(String
            .valueOf(mUpCameraPosition.target.longitude));
    mUpZoom.setText(String.valueOf(mUpCameraPosition.zoom));

}

private SupportMapFragment getMap() {
    return ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
}
```

Please help me....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65405/discussion-on-question-by-sonam-how-to-set-marker-in-center-of-google-map-in-and).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your *onTouchUp()* method like that:

```
    @Override
        public void onTouchUp(MotionEvent event) {
            mUpCameraPosition = getMap().getMap().getCameraPosition();
            getMap().getMap().clear();// to remove previous marker
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() 
                                    .title(/*YOUR TITLE*/) 
                                    .position(new LatLng(mUpCameraPosition.target.latitude, mUpCameraPosition.target.longitude)) 
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable./*YOUR IMAGE*/)); 
            getMap().getMap().addMarker(options)
            updateCameraPositionData();
        }
```

PS: For better performance, if you use the same resource icon, you can add a *BitmapDescriptor* variable in your class to use it instead of creating it each time in "BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable./*YOUR IMAGE*/)"

Comment: I need the address like - 14,5th Cross,Lakshmi Layout, Munnekolala,, Near Lions Airport City Hospital , Marathahalli,, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037 on my title.... can you suggested me some method

Comment: to get adress from lat-long, (as i know) you should use google geocoding api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding . This is another example: http://techslides.com/convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-a-street-address